# Difference between these delete-list-item algorithms

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I wrote three algorithms for delete item/items from a single-linked list.
Number 1 works fine. Also number 2 works fine.
Number 3 doesn't work, and I know. But why number 3 is incorrect and what is the difference with the number 2 and the double pointer?

Number 1:

```
struct nodo * delete1(struct nodo * top, int data) {

struct nodo *current, *temp;

if(top->valore == data ) {
     current = top->next;
     free(top);
     top = current;
 }
 
 
     current = top;
     while (current->next)
     {
         if (current->next->valore == data)
         {
             temp = current->next->next;
             free(current->next);
             current->next = temp;
         }
         else
             current = current->next;
     }
 

return top;
}
```

Number 2:

```
void delete2(struct nodo **p, int k) {

while(*p) {
    if ((*p)->valore == k)
    {
        struct nodo * tmp = (*p)->next;
        free(*p);
        (*p) = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        p = &(*p)->next;
    }
    
}

}
```

Number 3:

```
struct nodo * delete3(struct nodo * top, int k) {
struct nodo * curr = top;
while(curr) {
    if(curr->d == k) {
        struct nodo * tmp = curr->next;
        free(curr);
        curr = tmp;
    }
    else curr = curr->next;
}
return top;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the three functions have different behaviors.

In the first function if the first node of the list has the value equal to the specified value then only this first node is deleted. Otherwise all nodes with the specified value are deleted.

But in any case even after you updated the function it can invoke undefined behavior for example when is called for an empty list or when a single node of the list was deleted.

In the second function all nodes (independent on whether the first node has the value equal to the specified value) with the value equal to the specified value are deleted.

The third function is entirely wrong because it changes the local variable `curr` instead of for example the variable top or any data member next of a node. That is in any case the function returns the previous value of the pointer top independent on whether the pointed node was deleted.

To make the behavior of the first function similarly to the behavior of the second function it should be defined the following way.

```
struct nodo * delete1(struct nodo * top, int data) 
{
    while ( top && top->valore == data ) 
    {
        struct nodo *temp = top->next;
        free( top );
        top = temp;
    }

    if ( top )
    {
        struct nodo *current = top;
        while (current->next)
        {
            if ( current->next->valore == data )
            {
                struct nodo *temp = current->next->next;
                free( current->next );
                current->next = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }

    return top;
}
```

Comment: But in the first function I can delete `else` statement and the function will delete head and also the next nodes, right?

Comment: @LuigiV. The else statement is not executed if the condition of the if statement evaluates to true.

Comment: @LuigiV. If you will remove else the function can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, I know. I mean if I delete else but keep the code in the else..Let me edit my code so you can see.

Comment: Now you can see first function again

Comment: @LuigiV. It is a bad idea to change such a way your question because this will confuse readers of the question and answers. But in any case your new provided function definition is incorrect. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you. My version is incorrect because I don't check `top`, right?

Comment: @LuigiV. You are not checking whether the pointer top is equal to NULL and you are ignoring the situation when in the beginning of the list there are adjacent elements with the specified value.